# Facing issue in rendering Rgraph in IE8 using jquery inside the parent html

Tags: jquery, rgraph

I have 2 html one calling other. using jquery.ready
the second JSP actually has the code of graph.
everything works fine in Firefox , Chrome, safari. and IE9

but things are not working on in IE8 using the ready method of jquery
is i access the  line.htm directly it works fine on IE8 also

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="htmls/js/RGraph.line.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 10]><script src="http://www.rgraph.net/excanvas/excanvas.js"  charset="UTF-8"></script><![endif]-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('parent');
$("#Graphvisualization").load('line.htm');});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Graphvisualization"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

src="http://www.rgraph.net/excanvas/excanvas.js"

Copy the file to your own server and use it from there.